# How can I Determine Which Source Files Were Used in an AOSP System Lib Binary?

Tags: android, build, shared-libraries, android-source

I am working on a project which involves binaries extracted from a device image which I have built myself from the AOSP. I'd like to check the licenses on the source files used to build it, but am not sure how to get a list of those files. I can rerun the build of the image at any time.

How get a list of those source files by module (eg from libutil.so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto your AOSP dir and run:
Find * -name Android.mk | grep "MODULE.*libutil"

It may take a while but you'll get the directory where the source code is at (that's where the Android.mk is at)